# artifactory_extra_conf not available in 6.1.0

Tags: docker, configuration, artifactory

The [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+with+Docker) states that extra configuration can be put in the `/artifactory_extra_conf` directory. This directory does not exist in the `artifactory-oss:6.1.0` docker image. When I create the directory myself it is not used, also I see no reference of it in the `/entrypoint-artifactory.sh` script.

Does anybody know if this behavior has changed and documentation is simply behind or that I'm maybe misinterpreting the docs?

Comment: This feature is only available in artifactory-pro.

Comment: Damn, I was afraid of that. Thank you for your answer!